# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode Error with JBPM 4.4

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, transactions, jbpm, lob

We are using Jbpm 4.4 as our 3rd party Business Process Management tool with Java 6.x. However So far we used it with Oracle DB and it worked well, but now we want to run it with PostgreSQL 12.x version DB.
So we integrated postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar (JDBC driver) and try to run it.
We have encountered below error in the run time.

Can anyone suggest what need to be done here to resolve the issue, **specially with JBPM 4.4**

We have already set

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
```

But that did not resolved our issue.

```
2021-05-05 06:41:57,670 ERROR [o-8443-exec-154] .AbstractFlushingEventListener          portaladmin@10.100.250.41   - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [org.jbpm.pvm.internal.lob.Lob]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2295) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2688) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:996) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1141) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:93) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.execute(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:67) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.untypedList(AbstractQuery.java:67) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.list(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:157) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.ProcessDeployer.checkKey(ProcessDeployer.java:133) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.ProcessDeployer.deploy(ProcessDeployer.java:92) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeployerManager.deploy(DeployerManager.java:46) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.RepositorySessionImpl.deploy(RepositorySessionImpl.java:62) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:47) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:33) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:42) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.SpringCommandCallback.doInTransaction(SpringCommandCallback.java:45) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) [spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:49) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.executeInNewEnvironment(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:53) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:40) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.RetryInterceptor.execute(RetryInterceptor.java:56) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.SkipInterceptor.execute(SkipInterceptor.java:43) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeploymentImpl.deploy(DeploymentImpl.java:90) [jbpm-pvm-4.4.jar:4.4]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess_aroundBody18(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:108) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess_aroundBody19$advice(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:92) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess_aroundBody20(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:1) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess_aroundBody22(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:106) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess_aroundBody23$advice(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:80) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.deployProcess(JbpmProcessDefinitionRepository.java:1) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody46(JbpmProcessService.java:178) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody47$advice(JbpmProcessService.java:92) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody48(JbpmProcessService.java:1) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody50(JbpmProcessService.java:178) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody51$advice(JbpmProcessService.java:80) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody52(JbpmProcessService.java:1) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess_aroundBody53$advice(JbpmProcessService.java:61) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.processes.jbpm.JbpmProcessService.deployProcess(JbpmProcessService.java:1) [com.abc.def.portal.processes-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody128(TaskController.java:611) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody129$advice(TaskController.java:58) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody130(TaskController.java:1) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody131$advice(TaskController.java:92) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody132(TaskController.java:1) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody134(TaskController.java:605) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody135$advice(TaskController.java:102) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody136(TaskController.java:1) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload_aroundBody137$advice(TaskController.java:55) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController.handleFormUpload(TaskController.java:1) [TaskController.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2349406.invoke(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:na]
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149) [cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67) [spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.task.TaskController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4f295537.handleFormUpload(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.security.IncompleteUserProfileFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody4(IncompleteUserProfileFilter.java:108) [IncompleteUserProfileFilter.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.security.IncompleteUserProfileFilter.doFilterInternal(IncompleteUserProfileFilter.java:89) [IncompleteUserProfileFilter.class:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.servlet.SsoRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter_aroundBody2(SsoRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:63) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.servlet.SsoRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SsoRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:58) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168) [spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.security.SSOAutoLoginFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody0(SSOAutoLoginFilter.java:67) [SSOAutoLoginFilter.class:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.partner.client.security.SSOAutoLoginFilter.doFilterInternal(SSOAutoLoginFilter.java:63) [SSOAutoLoginFilter.class:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody0(CsrfFilter.java:86) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:57) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.csrf.AjaxTimeoutFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody0(AjaxTimeoutFilter.java:45) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.csrf.AjaxTimeoutFilter.doFilterInternal(AjaxTimeoutFilter.java:31) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.timing.TimingServletFilter.doFilter_aroundBody2(TimingServletFilter.java:71) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.timing.TimingServletFilter.doFilter(TimingServletFilter.java:63) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.servlet.XFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody0(XFilter.java:56) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.servlet.XFilter.doFilterInternal_aroundBody1$advice(XFilter.java:64) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at com.abc.def.portal.ui.servlet.XFilter.doFilterInternal(XFilter.java:51) [com.abc.def.portal.ui-2.1.NOPSE19C.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
        at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar:42.2.19.jre6]
        at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:272) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar:42.2.19.jre6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.createBlob(PgPreparedStatement.java:1159) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar:42.2.19.jre6]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setBlob(PgPreparedStatement.java:1200) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar:42.2.19.jre6]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setBlob(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:495) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
        at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2025) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2271) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
        ... 160 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Though jbpm 4.4 is a very old version (currently at 7.54), try to update your schema and use bytea type for postgresql large objects.

If you're using JTA datasource, auto-commit setting is always true and it can not be changed. Try to change it to an xa-datasource

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed the data type to bytea  and I'm still getting that error. Yes this jbpm version is too old, we are still using it in our legacy application. Still some customers are using it, so we have to support it. However this is working with Oracle without any issue. I wonder what happen if I lower the postgre SQL driver version, I'm currently using postgresql-42.2.19.jre6.jar

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I was able to find out a solution for this.
I have changed the DB column to Bytea type in PostgreSQL and change the JBPM 4.4 implementation to use byte[] over java.sql.Blob (in org.jbpm.pvm.internal.lob.Lob class).